# C# Linq-to-SQL: find childrens up to three levels

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a shop with categories stored in database like below:

[image]

Categories are nested in each other using ParentCategoryId and root parent ID is 0.

I want to know how can I retrieve list of categories at most up to 3 levels not more than that?
**Note:** A thing that is important for me is that  the number of maximum level can be adjustable if possible by a input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

What about a loop for each level?

```
public void GetCategories(int level) {
   var categories = db.Categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == 0).ToList();
   var parents = categories.Select(c => c.Id);
   for (var ii = 0; ii < level; ii++) {
      var newCategories = db.Categories.Where(c => parents.Contains(c.ParentCategoryId).ToList();  
      parents = newCategories.Select(c => c.Id);
      categories = categories.Concat(newCategories);
}

   var result = categories;
}
```

I presumed you need all levels, not just the last one.

Comment: This is a good answer, however there is not shortcut or SQL query for this which avoids running the query for several time to get the final list?

Comment: Why would you need that? Premature "optimisation", you cannot be sure, if it's going to be faster/more efficient...